# Android - for loop terminating early

Tags: java, android, json, bitmap

I'm trying to manipulate a JSONArray, `rawJArr`, (taken from the Reddit API), and get the url and a bitmap (taken from the gfycat "API") from each object to create an ArrayList (`listing`) of `Highlight` instances which will be converted to a `CardView` containing a picture, a short description, and a link to the gfycat.

```
try {

    int count = 0;
    int highlightMax;
    Bitmap bitmap = null;
    Highlight curHighlight;
    myJSON = new JSONObject(rawJSON);
    curJSON = myJSON.getJSONObject("data");
    rawJArr = curJSON.getJSONArray("children");

    String strHighlightNo =  mySPrefs.getString("pref_highlightNo", "notFound");

    if(strHighlightNo.equals("notFound")) {
        Log.w("FT", "shared pref not found");
        return null;
    }

    highlightMax = Integer.parseInt(strHighlightNo);

    Log.w("Arr Length", Integer.toString(rawJArr.length()));
    Log.w("Highlight No", Integer.toString(highlightMax));

    for(int i=0; i < rawJArr.length(); i++) {

        Log.w("Count", Integer.toString(count));
        Log.w("I", Integer.toString(i));

        if(count == highlightMax) {
            Log.w("FT", "Breakpoint reached!");
            break;
        }

        curJSON = rawJArr.getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("data");

        String url = curJSON.getString("url");
        String[] parts = url.split("//");
        String imageUrl = "http://thumbs." + parts[1] + "-thumb100.jpg";

        try {
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream) new URL(imageUrl).getContent());
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // if there is no available picture, then don't include one in the Highlight
        if(bitmap == null) {
            Log.w("FT", "Null bitmap");
            curHighlight = new Highlight(curJSON.getString("title"), url, null);
            listing.add(curHighlight);
            count++;
        } else {
            Log.w("FT", "Bitmap Available");
            curHighlight = new Highlight(curJSON.getString("title"), url, bitmap);
            listing.add(curHighlight);
            count++;
        }

    }


    } catch(JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return listing;
    }
```

However, my for loop terminates way too early. The current JSONArray I'm using has a length of 25, and I've specified a `pref_highlightNo` of 15, but my for loop terminates after 6 iterations.

My `Log.w` tests in the for loop all record the same count (Count: 1, Integer: 1 - Count: 6, Integer: 6).

I'm struggling to see why my loop is terminating: there is no stack trace printed to my console, and my app doesn't crash.

Any idea what's going on?

Comment: have you used the debugger? What is the value of rawJarr.length()

Comment: @yts - 25, I log it right before I entered the for loop

Comment: keep debugging. Check the values of count and highlightmax on every iteration. Don't just log. Using the debugger will give you step by step analysis.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the issue was specific to the last url I was trying to create to get the required gfycat - I didn't have any code to handle cases where the link began with `http://www`.